# How to pass data from tab bar controller to each tab before they are loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am sending an HTTP request to a website, and can there are rate restrictions (5 per minute) so I just want to get the data once when the app opens, (my tab bar controller), and then pass that data to each of my tabs. How would I be able to do this. Thank you

Comment: why don't you store the data somewhere like NSUserDefault or database , and when each tab loads get the stored data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each tab you have to get the tabBarController reference and using that reference you can access the values.

```
MyTabBarController *tabBarObj = (MyTabBarController*)self.tabBarController;
NSLog(@"%@",tabBarObj.responseValue)
```